# Dependency property's set doesn't update its value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have popup and i have a animation using its horizontal and vertical offsets. This Animation takes these offsets as values and have a simple storyboard. For the 1st time it works fine and  the second time, the Horizontal offset was not updating the value. I dono why its like this. I have checked the Dp with the property changed handlers, its not get changed. Retains its old value. There is no binding at all, value is set directly.

What might be the reason for this. Any idea on this??

```
        var duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
        horizontalDoubleAnimation = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        verticalDoubleAnimation = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        horizontalDoubleAnimation.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(duration);
        verticalDoubleAnimation.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(duration);
        horizontalDoubleAnimation.EasingFunction = new CircleEase();
        verticalDoubleAnimation.EasingFunction = new CircleEase();
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames horizontalAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames verticalAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        horizontalAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(horizontalDoubleAnimation);
        verticalAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(verticalDoubleAnimation);
        reverseAnimationStoryboard = new Storyboard { Duration = duration };
        reverseAnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(horizontalAnimationUsingKeyFrames);
        reverseAnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(verticalAnimationUsingKeyFrames);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(horizontalAnimationUsingKeyFrames, this.DraggablePopup);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(verticalAnimationUsingKeyFrames, this.DraggablePopup);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(horizontalAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("HorizontalOffset"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(verticalAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("VerticalOffset"));
        this.DraggablePopup.Resources.Add("storyboard", reverseAnimationStoryboard);
```

Comment: `this.DraggablePopup.HorizontalOffset = Math.Round(horizontalOffset);` like this value for horizontaloffset were set. `horizontalOffset` its just a double value.

Comment: Is the VerticalOffset working after the 1st time?
Where and how are you updating the VerticalOffset and HorizontalOffset?

Comment: Its not get updating after 1st time.. am updating while mouse move..

Comment: @FHnainia: Any idea on this?

Comment: You haven't shown any code that's setting any values. This code is creating a Storyboard and saving it as a resource, but not running it (which would result in setting values). Are you running this code repeatedly and expecting something to happen?

Comment: @JohnBowen: Yes this code creates a storyboard and save it in a resource. this will execute only when initialize. while the mouse move the values are updated (look at the 1st comment).